# Trying to get property of non-object In PHP LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

im sending a request from web-sniffer where email=qqqq@gmail.com which i have in my database :
here is my controller's code

```
$email = $request["email"];
        $user = DB::select('select * from users where email = :email', ['email' => $email]);
       var_dump($user);
        //echo $user->email ;
```

but when uncomment the echo i get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8w3k.png)

so the problem is my $user is not empty but when i try to access a proprety i get the "Trying to get property of non-object" error
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're getting is an array. With just one element, but an array nonetheless, so you can access the property with

```
echo $user[0]->email;
```

may I suggest using a better approach, like Fluent for example:

```
$user = \DB::table('users')
           ->where('email', $request['email'])
           ->first();
```

or Eloquent:

```
$user = User::whereEmail($request['email'])->first();
```

This way you get just one record (`first()`), and you can access the property like you're doing now:

```
if ($user) {
   $email = $user->email;
}
```